# Javascript: promise.resolve() statement valid?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

As I understand, `Promise` is a function of window object.

**Console View (Chrome)**

```
window.hasOwnProperty('Promise') // true

window.Promise // ƒ Promise() { [native code] }
```

But what I don't understand is how can a `Promise.resolve()` be a valid statement since it Promise is a function, not an object. Nor am I calling the promise function, like this `window.promise()` so that it then returns an object which has a `resolve` method.

Kindly clear this.

Thanks

Comment: In JavaScript, everything (except [Primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)) is an object.

Answer (score 4):

Functions can have properties on them as well:

```js
class MyClass {
  static fn() {
    console.log('fn running');
  }
}

const m = new MyClass();
MyClass.fn();
```

The actual source code of `window.Promise` may be hidden, but just like `MyClass` above, that doesn't stop the function itself from being able to have properties.

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Promise));
```

Answer (score 3):

> But what I don't understand is how can a Promise.resolve() be a valid statement since it Promise is a function, not an object.

In JavaScript, functions are a type of object.

```js
alert("This is an alert. You see it because a function was called.");

alert.foo = 1;

alert(`There is a property on this function with the value: ${alert.foo}`);

console.log(`Alert is an instance of Function: ${alert instanceof Function}`);
console.log(`Alert is an instance of Number: ${alert instanceof Number}`);
console.log(`Alert is an instance of Object: ${alert instanceof Object}`);
```